# How to fix those ugly deformations?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, surface-deform

[image]

How can i make it so the mesh deforms nicely?

Here is blend file [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology is causing you trouble:

[image]

For something like this I'd recommend either all-quads or a mix of quads and trigons, but you have a bunch of n-gons at one end of your cylinder, and the rest of the quads are too long and thin.

It's probably best to recreate the cylinder, 8 vertices and Cap Fill Type: Nothing.  Then scale to the length/width you want and Apply the scale (Ctrl-A).  Then go into Edit Mode and put enough loop cuts that all the faces are short fat quads, not the long ones this has.  Try your armature on that -- if you're still having trouble I'd say put a Subdivision modifier on the cylinder.

It might be helpful to search for tutorials on quads topology for more info.